# reverse numbers in a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have some coordinate data that is `lng,lat` however I need it `lat,lng`

I have them in a list of tuples and need to switch them around:

```
myList = [(-87.93897686650001, 41.8493707892),
 (-87.93893322819997, 41.8471652588),
 (-87.9292710931, 41.8474548975),
 (-87.91960917239999, 41.8477438951),
 (-87.91927828050001, 41.8404034535)]
```

I have tried

```
newList = []
for i in range(len(myList)):
    for c, x in reversed(list(enumerate(myList[i]))):
        newList.append(x)
```

I get the below output, which is close

```
[41.8493707892,
 -87.93897686650001,
 41.8471652588,
 -87.93893322819997,
 41.8474548975,
 -87.9292710931,
 41.8477438951,
 -87.91960917239999,
 41.8404034535,
 -87.91927828050001]
```

But I am looking for

```
[(41.8493707892, -87.93897686650001),
     (41.8471652588, -87.93893322819997),
     (41.8474548975, -87.9292710931),
     (41.8477438951, -87.91960917239999),
     (41.8404034535, -87.91927828050001)]
```

ideally i would like to do this all in the nested for-loop; but I do not care if I have to do something with the newList to group the pairs.

As always any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're really attached to the nested for-loop, it's probably easiest to use this sort of list comprehension:

```
newlist=[i[::-1] for i in myList]

>>> newlist
[(41.8493707892, -87.93897686650001), (41.8471652588, -87.93893322819997), (41.8474548975, -87.9292710931), (41.8477438951, -87.91960917239999), (41.8404034535, -87.91927828050001)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easy with list comprehension.

```
[(b,a) for a,b in myList]
```